# Is running a gas stove more efficient than turning on an in-building radiator?

Tags: thermodynamics

It's cold in your studio apartment and you have two options:

1. Turn on the four burners and the oven on your gas stove; or,
2. Crank open the two small radiators.

Both deliver heat directly to the space of your apartment and we can ignore, for the moment at least, the impact the location of each source might have on how efficiently it heats the space. Is one method more efficient than the other?

It seems to me that, if so, the difference will come in the difference in efficiency we might find between the building's boiler and the apartment's stove. For example, while your stove might extract as heat only 75% of the available energy of the gas the building boiler extracts 90%. If they have the same efficiency, it would seem, we would have minimal to no difference, as then we're in the domain simply of energy exchange from one medium to another.

Is this the right way to think about this question?

Comment: Are you going to consider the ventilation needs in your apartment and its impact on energy balance?

Comment: The boiler is probably vented which will waste some heat but also get rid of fumes.  The stove might be more efficient because this is not done but it may also be less healthy to do it a lot.  I considered this when my boiler failed but decided agsinst it.  I hate to use electricity for heating but, nonetheless, I bought a fan heater for use until the boiler was repaired.

Comment: @JonCuster Perhaps if this were a long-term solution. However, in the question, I am thinking about timescales on the order of an hour, which, I hope, don't require ventilation.

Comment: Neglecting transportation and manufacturing costs, $\eta_\text{heat pump} > \eta_\text{on-site combustion} > \eta_{resistive}$, but there is no trivial way to disentangle caes within a single category.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a gas stove that is not externally vented, and a gas central heat system, the stove will probably be more thermally efficient. I would not recommend using your stove, as it releases dangerous carbon monoxide and other waste gasses into your room, and is not intended for extended use without ventilation. This being said, with the stove all of the heat from the burned gas goes into the room. With central heat, the burned gas heats a media that is circulated to transfer heat. Then the burned gas, still containing some of the heat, is vented to the outside. WARNING: if you use gas heat (especially unvented stoves) it is a good idea to have carbon monoxide alarms, and smoke alarms.

Answer (score 0):

From the point of physics answer seems simple. Radiator in order to get hot, also has burner (assuming it’s gas), located likely in basement. So for same amount of gas burnt (by stove and radiator’s burners), it’s heat energy in case of radiator, has to be transferred through pipes, from basement, where some energy is lost in transfer, as well some heat is lost in basement (where hot water boiler radiates some of it’s heat to basement’s air instead of studio). If studio is on the first floor, directly above boiler, some of this energy will be recovered by heating studio’s floor, which then transfers its heat to air. Nevertheless, some energy must be consumed on heating air in basement itself, as well, pipes itself, and building structures pipes run through - which are all loss. Burning stove transfers (almost - forget kinetic energy of air) ALL its heat energy directly to studio’s air without any losses at all. Hence, even not necessarily the healthiest way, burning stove burners is more cost efficient.
I must admit I was asking myself same question. I was thinking, well, warmed radiator keep heat and radiates it longer than heated air which cools fast. How that influences efficiency? Minimum thought reveals, answer is actually quite simple. From conservation of energy law, if radiator warms air longer, it is only because it absorbed more heat energy (it took longer and more gas to heat it). This has no significance on efficiency. Only thing which has significance on efficiency are energy spent on heating unintended bodies and objects: as air in basements, walls, pipes etc (losses) OR more precisely, heat energy which is generated and eventually transferred to outside, BYPASSING  intended body to be heated (air in the studio). It is really high-school level question. Nevertheless I was puzzled by it myself. By giving little thought to answering your question I really answered my own (which turns our was not that difficult at all). Not a first time I finding out, by answering people’s questions, you really answering your own.